# Error with React Native Expo after following SimCoder Instagram Clone

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I Have same error with this function:

```
export function fetchUsersData(uid){
    return((dispatch, getState) => {
         const found = getState().userState.users.some(el => el.uid === uid) //this element will try to check if the uid is in the array users: []
        if(!found){
            firebase.firestore().collection("users")
            .doc(uid)
            .get().then((snapshot) => {
                    if(snapshot.exists){
                        let user = snapshot.data()
                        user.uid = snapshot.id
                        dispatch({type : USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE, user})
                        dispatch(fetchUsersFollowingPosts(uid));

                        console.log(snapshot)
                    }
                })
                
            }
       }
       )
}
```

Trying to feed followings posts at this SimCoder video https://youtu.be/83OxEjtGvgY after 22:52 getting the error:

> ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'getState().userState.users.some')